# Static vs New/Malloc

Tags: c++, c, static

I was wondering if people could shed some light on the uses of "static." I have never run into an issue where I have explicitly declared a variable or method as static. I understand that when declaring something as "static" it gets stuffed into the data segment of your program, similar to globals, and hence the variable is accessible for the run of your program. If this is the case, why not just make a static variable a global variable. Hell, why not just throw this variable on the heap using a new or a malloc, both methods ensure the variable will be available for you throughout the run of your program.

Comment: `void foo() {auto p = new int{}; /*stuff/*}` Oh shoot, lost pointer and new memory every time.

Comment: You have to be willing to actually feel enthusiastic about a huge number of details and pedantry if you want a clear understanding: storage, linkage, names, variables, objects, declarations, definitions, scope, blocks, lifetime... Unless you really care, just stick with the simple operational semantics and move on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static` has multiple meanings in C, and C++ heaps on even more.

In a file scope declaration (what I think the question is about), static controls the visibility of an identifier.

Let's set aside C++ and use the C concepts.

File scope identifiers which name objects or functions have *linkage*.  Linkage can be *external* (program-wide) or *internal* (within one translation unit).

`static` specifies internal linkage.

This is important because if a name with internal linkage appears in multiple units, those occurrences are not related.  One module can have a static `foo` function and another one in the same program can have a different `foo` function. They both exist and are reachable by the name `foo` from their respective units.

This is not possible with external linkage: there must be one `foo`.

`malloc` creates an object which is potentially available everywhere in a program, as long as it is not freed, but in a different sense. The object is available if you have its pointer. A pointer is a kind of "run time name": an access key to get to the object.  Linkage makes an object or function available if you know its name (at compile time) and if that object and function has the right kind of linkage relative to where you're trying to access it from.

In a dynamic operating system in which multiple programs come into life and terminate, the storage for its static data and functions (whether they have external or internal linkage) is in fact dynamically allocated. The system routine which loads a program has to do something similar to `malloc` to fetch memory for all of the fixed areas of the program.

Sometimes C programs use `malloc` even for "singleton" objects that are referenced globally via global pointers. These objects behave like de-facto static variables since they basically have a lifetime which is almost that of the entire program, and are accessed through the pointer, which is accessed by name. This is useful if the objects have properties (such as size) that is not known until run time, or if their initialization is expensive and they are not always needed (only when certain cases occur in the program).

---

Supplemental factoids about `static` and `extern`:

- In C, at file scope, `extern` ensures that the declaration of an object, where an initializer is omitted, is in fact a declaration. Without `extern` it is a tentative definition, but if an initializer is present, then it is a definition.
- In C, at file scope `extern` doesn't mean "this declaration has external linkage", surprisingly. An `extern` declaration inherits linkage from a previous declaration of the same name.
- A block-scope `extern` in C means "this name, which is being introduced into this scope, refers to the external definition *with external linkage*". The linkage is inherited from a previous file-scope declaration of the name, if it exists, otherwise it is external.
- A block-scope `static` on an object controls not linkage, but storage duration. A `static` object is not instantiated each time on entry into the block; a single copy of it exists, and can be initialized prior to program startup. (In C++, non-constant expressions can initialize such object or its members; in that case, initialization occurs on the first execution of the block).
- A block-scope `static` function declaration declares a function with internal linkage.
- There is no way, in a block scope, to declare an external object name which has internal linkage. Paradoxically, the first `extern` declaration in the following snippet is correct, but the second, block-scope one, is erroneous!

  ```
  static int name; /* external name with internal linkage */
  extern int name; /* redundant redeclaration of the above */

  void foo(void)
  {
     int name; /* local variable shadowing external one */

     {
        /* attempt to "punch through" shadow and reach external: */
        extern int name; /* ERROR! */
     }
  }
  ```
- Clearly, the word "external" has an ambiguous meaning between "outside of any function" and "program-wide linkage" and this ambiguity is embroiled in the `extern` keyword.
- In C++, `static` takes on additional meanings. In a class declaration, it declares "static member functions" which belong to the class scope and have the same access to class instances as non-static member functions do, but are not invoked on objects (do not have the implicit `this` parameter). Class data members marked `static` have a single class-wide instance; they are not instantiated per-object. (Unfortunately, they don't participate properly in inheritance like true object-oriented class variables, which can be overridden in a derived class to be instance or vice versa.)
- In C++, a privacy similar to internal linkage can be achieved using an unnamed `namespace` rather than `static`. Namespaces make the internal/external linkage concept mostly an obsolete mechanism for C compatibility.
- C++ involves `extern` in the special `extern "LANG"` syntax (e.g. `extern "C"`).
- `static_cast` is unrelated to `static`; what they have in common is "static" meaning "prior to program run time": static storage is determined prior to run time, and the conversion of a static casts is also determined at compile time (without run-time-type info).

Comment: Thanks this explained it very well and clearly. I guess its all about use case and design of your program. Nevertheless good to know what they are

Comment: I will stick to my globals and mallocs

Comment: Globals are evil.  Dynamic memory should be avoided.  Multiple writers can set a global variable, there is no control or restricted access.  Dynamic memory allocations can produce memory leaks or fragmentation (which needs garbage collection).  So learn to minimize globals and refrain from dynamic memory allocations.  Especially on embedded systems.